# Who voiced Nuka-Girl?

Tags: fallout-4

A quick Google search seemingly answered the question: Courtenay Taylor, right? Not quite. Clicking on the immediately listed link, the voice actress' [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Courtenay_Taylor) lists her as voicing the Sole Survivor. Investigating further, as VAs often voice multiple characters, I looked at her list of credits, but Nuka-Girl was not one of them. Naturally, I then looked at the [character page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Nuka-Girl) for Nuka-Girl. However, Fandom did not have any listing for a voice actress. Gamepedia's [*Nuka-Girl's dialoge*](https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Nuka-Girl%27s_dialogue) page also lacked a VA credit, citing only this for her voice: "DLC04_Announcer_NukaGalaxy_NPCFNukaGirl".

Finally, it seemed like I found a potential voice actress at IMDb's Fallout 4 [credit list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4741306/fullcredits), but none of the ladies credited with lending their voices to the Nuka-World DLC ([Anjali Bhimani](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0080401/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t167), [Corri English](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0257598/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t170), [Laura Post](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3677958/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t171), and [Jan Johns](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1696096/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t23)) were credited as voicing Nuka-Girl.

After spending more time searching than I care to admit, I still don't have an answer to my question: Who voiced Nuka-Girl?

Comment: I'm digging into this too. The Fallout Wikia for Nuka World voice acting also identifies uncredited roles (unlike Imdb), but the Nuka-Girl voice is the still not identified. I think we'd have to message one of the voice actresses to figure this out.

Comment: This is some Nick Robinson-level stuff if the voice actress's credit is not there. It could be a Vocaloid, but I doubt it.

Comment: How about getting the credits for the song in the trailer? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIneiOpuS2M
...
https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Nuka-World_theme_song - COPILOT Music and Sound
...
hmmm... ... And this guy helped make it... https://mgarrettsteele.wordpress.com/video-game-music/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [character page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Nuka-Girl) got the answer in September: [Anna Graves](https://twitter.com/gravyvoice/status/776497708815089664)

Comment: Huh. More than 6 years old, that tweet. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, the tweet ranks first with "vo nukagirl" in Google now. But didn't in September 2020 (at least when using the Google tools to define the time range)